# Trying to make my site responsive using bootstrap. Can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a website that is responsive, with the use of bootstrap. However, as you see, it is definitely not responsive.

One of the noticeable problems is that the text goes outside of the divs they are in, as soon as I reduce the size of my browser window. Also my images stacks up weirdly, when doing this.

I know its a mess but I hope someone can guide me a bit. I'm not asking for a full guide to correct each element.

Regards,

Jonas

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body{
    color: white;
 
}

.container {
 margin: 0 10px 0;
}

header {
 background-color: #0f1011;
 height: 100%;
}

header .top {
 height: 18%;
}

.top h1 span {
 color: #fff;
}

.top p {
 color: #fff;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.top ul li {
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 10px; 
}

.top ul li a {
 color: #fff;
}

.top ul li a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;

}

.top ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    margin-top: 20px;
}


header .centerImage {
 height: 60%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #9ca4af;
}

.centerImage img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

header .sloganAndSocial {
 height: 22%;
}



.sloganAndSocial h4 {
 float: right;
}


.contentSection {
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 100%;
}


.contentSection aside {
 background-color: #d5d9e0;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d5d9e0, #fff); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#d5d9e0, #fff); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d5d9e0, #fff); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#d5d9e0, #fff); /* Standard syntax */
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 46px;
}

aside h3 {
 padding: 10px 0 7px 0;
}

aside .sideInfo {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.sponsors {
 background-color: #d5dded;
 height: 70%;
}

.sponsers img {
 margin: 6px 3px;
}

footer {
 background-color: black;
 color: #fff;
 height: 70%;
}

footer p {
 line-height: 180%;
}

footer h3 {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

footer p span {
 color: #b5b5b5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NORDIC BARISTACUB</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" >
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <h1><span>NORDIC </span>BARISTACUP</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                            <form><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."></form>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <p>be together &nbsp;act together &nbsp; learn together</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2011 EVENT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">NORDIC ROASTER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">RESULTS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="centerImage">
                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!"/>
            </div>
            <div class="sloganAndSocial">
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <h3>"To create an environment in which knowledge<br>about coffee and its sphere can be obtained</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                            <h4>Social icons coming here!</h4>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="contentSection">
            <div class="articles">
                <aside>
                    <div class="sideInfo">
                       <h3>NBC Shop</h3>
                        <p>Your shopping cart is empty</p>
                        <p><a href="#">Visit the shop</a></p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="sideInfo">
                        <h3>Next Event</h3>
                        <p>NORDIC BARISTA CUP 2011<br>
                        Copenhagen, Denmark<br>
                        Dates : 25th - 27th August 2011<br>
                        Theme : SENSORY</p>
                        <p><a href="#">Sign up now</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sideInfo">
                        <h3>Scoreboard</h3>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>List of winners from past years</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2011</td><td>?</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2010</td><td>Sweden</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2009</td><td>Denmark</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2007</td><td>Sweden</td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>
                            <td>2006</td><td>Norway</td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>
                            <td>2005</td><td>Norway</td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>
                            <td>2004</td><td>Denmark</td>
                        </tr>    
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsors">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Nordic Barista Cup Sponsors</h3>    
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" /> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" /> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" /> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="130" height="90" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="container-fluid" id="footerH">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>About Nordic Barista</h3>
                    <p>The vision within the Nordic Barista Cup is:<br><br><span>"To create an environment in which knowledge about coffee and its sphere can be obtained"</span><br><br>
                    '...create an environment...'<br>
                    Combined with personally absorption having the oportunity to see and experience countries, people, traditions etc. will always serve as a source of inspiration in our daily work.<br>
                    The organization behind the Nordic Barista Cup see it as its main purpose to be a part of creating this forum in which people can meet, bond and achieve further knowledge.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>NBC Flickr Stream</h3>     
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-1">
                            <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <img src="img/coffeecup.jpg" alt="bo!" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>           
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>Contact</h3>
                    <p>Nordic Barista Cup<br><b></b>
                    <span>?????????<br>
                    1160 Copenhagen K<br>
                    555 555 555<br>
                    CVR: 555555<br>
                    Email: aaaaa@na.com</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
 
 <!--   
<img src="img/bo.jpg" alt="bo!"/>
-->


        <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also call your CSS file after bootstrap ..

Answer (score 0):

If this works without you own style, then it is the fault of your own styles. I would suggest you to comment out all you styles, an uncomment them one by one and see where the problem is. I would think it has something to do with changing the display of divs or alike.

Edit: You have to add container.